# Is the Apriori algorithm suitable for database tuples?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data, algorithms, association-rules

**Problem description:**

I need to use an association rule algorithm that lets me use database tuples and I think Apriori is a good option, but I am not sure.

---

**Starting point:**

I know the Apriori algorithm works in itemsets provided the items are independent one from each other, let's say:

```
T1: {Onions, Beer, Diapers}
T2: {Chili, Onions, Pizza}
T3: {Beer, Chili, Onions}
...
```

This would imply building a table of the form:

```
    -------------------//
    |  Onions |  Beer
|----------------------//
|T1 |    1    |   1
|T2 |    1    |   0
|----------------------//
```

Being the rows the transactions, the columns the items and a 0 or a 1 in the cell if the item is in the transaction or not.

---

**Problem details:**

I am using a beer database in which I have tuples of different kinds of beer, for example:

```
 id       name             type      country       liters   volume   container
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 xxx  The Jolly Joker    Pale Ale   Netherlands    Regular   Mild      Can
```

...being the upper row the column names and the lower one a sample tuple.

I want to find, given a set of tuples - like a shopping cart of 7 beers -, find rules of association that can fit that cart, as it follows:

```
{Pale Ale, Netherlands} -> {Bottle}
```

I am doubting if the Apriori algorithm can mine anything on this kind of data structure: one possibility would be treating every single value (regardless the column name) as an item of an itemset and after running the algorithm, ignoring the senseless sets (for example, {Netherlands, Germany, Blonde}).

I don't know if that approach would compromise the algorithm's reliability, if there exists a better way of getting the rules I need or if I am just using the wrong algorithm and there's one I don't know that fits my specifications.